# DNS Settings in Adapter

Tags: dns, network-adapter

**What are these settings for? And what should one do with them if they're using a VPN and its DNS servers?**

as seen here: [image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [serverbrain](https://www.serverbrain.org/maintenance-2003/configuring-advanced-dns-settings.html):

> The **DNS server list** is used only for the network interface you're configuring. This allows you to use different DNS servers for Network Interface Cards that are connected to different networks.

In general case, unless you need to use a pool of DNS name servers that your machine will contact for DNS resolution in a particular order, you don't need to update this setting.

As long as you have set your adapter's `Preferred DNS server` and `Alternate DNS server` settings according to your VPN provider's nameserver under `Use the following DNS server addresses` option, you are good to go.

Now coming to DNS suffix, let's take a scenerio from [serverbrain](https://www.serverbrain.org/maintenance-2003/configuring-advanced-dns-settings.html):

> Say your primary DNS suffix is `hsv.chellis.net` and your connection-specific suffix is `eng.hsv.chellis.net`. When this radio button (`Append Primary And Connection Specific DNS Suffixes`) is active, and you initiate a DNS query for a machine named **hawk**, DNS will first look for `hawk.hsv.chellis.net` and then for `hawk.eng.hsv.chellis.net`.

So unless you are operating from a private organization or institution's network with its own DNS nameservers, you won't need to update the DNS suffix settings on this window either.

If you feel curious to learn more, check out this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/303030/583923).

Comment: what about the setting "register this dns connections addresses in dns"?

Comment: **DNS registration** is where a mapping takes place between the network name and its provider IP addresses over a physical adapter that can reach a DNS server.
Windows DNS client can register and dynamically update its resource records (**A** and **PTR**) with a DNS server whenever changes occur.

This setting allows you to register the IP address for this connection in DNS under the computer's _fully qualified domain name_. Basically, it registers **A** and **PTR** resource records for the first IP address that is configured on the adapter of your computer.